# BASH: for _i in /location/file*.log is looping when it should not?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, increment

OK, this is blowing my mind a little.  It's a stupid little nuance of BASH that is obviously eluding me.  I write a logfile and I'm trying to increment it each time I run the program.  There are probably easier and more practical ways to do this, but at a core level, I need to understand why the following code is doing what it is doing:

```
$ function stupid() { local lc=0; for i in /drvsoft/shred*.log; do (( lc+=1 )); done; echo $lc; }
$ stupid
1
$ ls /drvsoft/shred*.log
ls: cannot access '/drvsoft/shred*.log': No such file or directory
```

Is there something I don't understand about for i in loops?  There is literally no i in; why is this incrementing?

Answer (score 1):

If `/drvsoft/shred*.log` doesn't match any files, the word remains unchanged, i.e. the loop iterates once with `i='/drvsoft/shred*.log'`.
To change the behaviour, you can

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer!  What, if anything might be relevant side-effects of adjusting this setting in the following circumstance: writing a somewhat complex tool to, among other things, identify the presence of files titled /dev/sd* (and then place each into an array if it is not explicitly in a separate exclude list).

Comment: You can always set it back with `shopt -u nullglob`. Also, to fail on no matching files rather than return a list or nothing, you can use `shopt -s failglob`.